# How to implement 4 quick taps(in 0.8 seconds) in android using appium?

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-java

I have tried TapAction, MultiTouch, but it is taking more time then 0.8 seconds. If any solution available, please respond

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by adding a for loop accordingly?

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
for i in range(1, 5):
    actions = TouchAction(driver)
    actions.tap(element)
    actions.perform()
```